# Decodebin decodes audio instead of video

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I have gstreamer pipeline:

```py
import cv2
src = "rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/cam/realmonitor?channel=1subtype=0"
pipeline = f'rtspsrc location="{src}" user-id="xxxx" user-pw="xxxxx" ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink'
video = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

try:
    while True:
        print(video.read())
finally:
    video.release()
```

and it fails when im running it on webcam that has audio and video stream

```
0:00:00.446758152 28582 0x7f9ea4069f70 WARN                 default grammar.y:510:gst_parse_no_more_pads:<decodebin0> warning: Delayed linking failed.
0:00:00.446790070 28582 0x7f9ea4069f70 WARN                 default grammar.y:510:gst_parse_no_more_pads:<decodebin0> warning: failed delayed linking some pad of GstDecodeBin named decodebin0 to some pad of GstVideoConvert named videoconvert0
0:00:02.371445473 28582 0x56051634bc50 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5653:gst_rtspsrc_loop:<rtspsrc0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:02.371481556 28582 0x56051634bc50 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5653:gst_rtspsrc_loop:<rtspsrc0> error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
0:00:02.376634686 28582 0x56051634bc50 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5999:gst_rtspsrc_try_send:<rtspsrc0> send interrupted
0:00:02.376674041 28582 0x56051634bc50 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:8246:gst_rtspsrc_pause:<rtspsrc0> PAUSE interrupted
```

I generated graph:
[image: Pipeline]

It shows, that it fails because decodebin starts decoding audio instead of video. So videoconvert fails to link.

How to ignore audio stream from the rtspsrc and make sure, that decodebin will decode only video stream?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the log more carefully for any hints. The pipeline looks ok and it should be able to connect the video path. Do you have any H.264 decoders installed? Does it support the H.264 level and profile that the stream is configured at?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my pipeline to

```
pipeline = f'rtspsrc location="{src}" user-id="xxxx" user-pw="xxxxx" ! decodebin ! application/x-rtp,media=(string)video ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink'
```

And it works. Decodebin successfully connects to the videoconvert